# select specific row in one table and insert other table using google-apps-script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

table name : select item=mobile in test_tbl and insert other table name is other_tbl using google-apps-script(google execl sheet).

[image]

Code:

```
function readFromTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(100);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM test_table where Price ="100"');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';        
      var cell_4 = rowString ;
    }    
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No.but i can get my purpose....what i need.

Comment: Please explain what is it that you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: i want to pick specific row in one table and insert that row in other table using google-apps-script

Comment: Insert into a (x) select b.y from my table where b.z = n

Comment: i did not get that logic .code please if it possible . @Strawberry